# Satisfy 3 conditions in a If/Else statement php page

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, require-once

I need to satisfy 3 different conditions in an if/else statement that `require_once`s a file in a specific folder My problem is that when my page is loaded my function satisfy only two conditions. I'd like to know if there's a better method to define this function:

```
     if ($sel_year <= '2016') {
          if ($sel_month >= '09') {
              require_once 'tab2.php';
              if ($sel_month <= '08') {
                  require_once 'tab1.php';
              } else require_once 'tab3.php';
          }
     }
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: `elseif ($sel_month <= '08') {`

Comment: Aside from attempting to compare strings with integer comparators, what do you mean by "satisfy 3 different conditions"? Exactly which conditions should be satisfied?